# Bruteforce program in python 3.6

Tags: python-3.6

I need to write a bruteforce program in python to iterate from "aaaaaaa" till "xxxxxxx" and determine how many guesses it takes to reach it.
How can I iterate from "aaaaaaa" to "xxxxxxx" with each iteration changing one alphabet from the right i.e. after the first iteration "aaaaaaa" should be "aaaaaab"?
Also, after an alphabets reaches "z" , it changes the adjacent left alphabet by one and goes back to "a".

Answer (score 0):

This is pseudo code for you to giving you an idea how to implement it though this platform is not thought to take your job and program the things for you. Hope that helps.

```
a={'a',....,'z'}
i1=0, i2=0, i3=0, i4=0, i5=0
while a[i1] <= 'z':
  while a[i2] <= 'z':
    while a[i3] <= 'z':    
      while a[i4] <= 'z':
        while a[i5] <= 'z':
          outString = a[i1] + a[i2] + a[i3] + a[i4] + a[i5]
          i5 = i5+1
        i4 = i4+1
        i5 = 0
      i3 = i3+1
      i4 = 0
    i2 = i2+1
    i3 = 0
  i1 = i1+1
  i2 = 0
```

Comment: Thanks @falkb . It surely will be helpful